# Unsupported operand type error in python code

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

SO when i run the code below:

```
from pylab import plt
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

z = open( 'WGTutorial/ZoneA.dat','r' ).readlines()
z = [ i.strip().split() for i in z[10:] ]
z = np.array( z, dtype=np.float )
z = DataFrame( z, columns=['x','y','thk','por','perm','lperm','lpermp','lpermr'] )

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter( z.x, z.y, c=z.por, cmap='gray' )
ax.set_aspect(1)
plt.xlim(-1500,22000)
plt.ylim(-1500,17500)
plt.xlabel('Easting [m]')
plt.ylabel('Northing [m]')
plt.title('Porosity %') ;

def SVh( P, h, bw ):
    '''
    Experimental semivariogram for a single lag
    '''
    pd = squareform( pdist( P[:,:2] ) )
    N = pd.shape[0]
    Z = list()
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(i+1,N):
            if( pd[i,j] >= h-bw )and( pd[i,j] <= h+bw ):
                Z.append( ( P[i,2] - P[j,2] )**2.0 )
    return np.sum( Z ) / ( 2.0 * len( Z ) )

def SV( P, hs, bw ):
    '''
    Experimental variogram for a collection of lags
    '''
    sv = list()
    for h in hs:
        sv.append( SVh( P, h, bw ) )
    sv = [ [ hs[i], sv[i] ] for i in range( len( hs ) ) if sv[i] > 0 ]
    return np.array( sv ).T

def C( P, h, bw ):
    '''
    Calculate the sill
    '''
    c0 = np.var( P[:,2] )
    if h == 0:
        return c0
    return c0 - SVh( P, h, bw )

# part of our data set recording porosity
P = np.array( z[['x','y','por']] )
# bandwidth, plus or minus 250 meters
bw = 500
# lags in 500 meter increments from zero to 10,000
hs = np.arange(0,10500,bw)
sv = SV( P, hs, bw )
plt.plot( sv[0], sv[1], '.-' )
plt.xlabel('Lag [m]')
plt.ylabel('Semivariance')
plt.title('Sample Semivariogram') ;
#plt.savefig('sample_semivariogram.png',fmt='png',dpi=200)

def opt( fct, x, y, C0, parameterRange=None, meshSize=1000 ):
    if parameterRange == None:
        parameterRange = [ x[1], x[-1] ]
    mse = np.zeros( meshSize )
    a = np.linspace( parameterRange[0], parameterRange[1], meshSize )
    type(y)
    type(x)
    type(a)
    type(C0)
    for i in range( meshSize ):
        mse[i] = np.mean( ( y - fct( x, a[i], C0 ) )**2.0 )
    return a[ mse.argmin() ]

def spherical( h, a, C0 ):
    '''
    Spherical model of the semivariogram
    '''
    # if h is a single digit
    if type(h) == np.float64:
        # calculate the spherical function
        if h <= a:
            return C0*( 1.5*h/a - 0.5*(h/a)**3.0 )
        else:
            return C0
    # if h is an iterable
    else:
        # calcualte the spherical function for all elements
        a = np.ones( h.size ) * a
        C0 = np.ones( h.size ) * C0
        return map( spherical, h, a, C0 )

def cvmodel( P, model, hs, bw ):
    '''
    Input:  (P)      ndarray, data
            (model)  modeling function
                      - spherical
                      - exponential
                      - gaussian
            (hs)     distances
            (bw)     bandwidth
    Output: (covfct) function modeling the covariance
    '''
    # calculate the semivariogram
    sv = SV( P, hs, bw )
    # calculate the sill
    C0 = C( P, hs[0], bw )
    # calculate the optimal parameters
    param = opt( model, sv[0], sv[1], C0 )
    # return a covariance function
    covfct = lambda h, a=param: C0 - model( h, a, C0 )
    return covfct

sp = cvmodel( P, model=spherical, hs=np.arange(0,10500,500), bw=500 )
plt.plot( sv[0], sv[1], '.-' )
plt.plot( sv[0], sp( sv[0] ) ) ;
plt.title('Spherical Model')
plt.ylabel('Semivariance')
plt.xlabel('Lag [m]')
#plt.savefig('semivariogram_model.png',fmt='png',dpi=200)
```

The error i get is this;

```
  File "C:/Users/PANATEC/Documents/Python Scripts/GlacMIK/Kriging.py", line 118, in cvmodel
    param = opt( model, sv[0], sv[1], C0 )

  File "C:/Users/PANATEC/Documents/Python Scripts/GlacMIK/Kriging.py", line 81, in opt
    mse[i] = np.mean( ( y - fct( x, a[i], C0 ) )**2.0 )

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'map'
```

I migrated to python few days ago and i am having difficulty fixing it.

Can any one kindly help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. I used list (map( spherical, h, a, c0)). The python3 map functions returns an iterator and not a list directly.

Comment: It is interesting that this works, I thought you needed a numpy array for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is described in the error message: at that line of code, **y** is a *float*; the **fct** expression evaluates to a data type **map**.  You cannot subtract the map from the float.

As I trace your code, **fct** is a pre-defined function **spherical**.  What is the return type?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
return map( spherical, h, a, C0 )
```

With:

```
return spherical(h, a, C0 )
```